# pysnmp agent table implementation

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I am new to snmp. I am using pysnmp to program a snmp agent, I compiled the MIB with mibdump.py and got it running using this examples: http://www.nealc.com/blog/blog/2013/02/23/writing-an-snmp-agent-with-a-custom-mib-using-pysnmp/ http://www.cloud-rocket.com/2013/08/writing-custom-mib-for-pysnmp-agent/ and also some of the documentation from de pysnmp webpage. I can do a get,  a set and a walk on my agent, with variables that do not belong to a table. I cant do a walk on the table, I can do a get on half the objects, and I cant do a set on any of them. This is what I get when I try a get or a set on some of the objects. I thought it was something related to the way I was querying the table, but there is no consistency between one object and another, even if they seem the exact same.

```
pysnmp$ snmpset -v2c -c private localhost 1.3.6.1.4.1.1206.4.2.3.3.2.1.3.0 i 1
Error in packet.
Reason: notWritable (That object does not support modification)
Failed object: iso.3.6.1.4.1.1206.4.2.3.3.2.1.3.0
```

This is an object defind by mibdump.py like

```
fontName = MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 1206, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3), DisplayString().subtype(subtypeSpec=ValueSizeConstraint(0, 64))).setMaxAccess("readwrite")
if mibBuilder.loadTexts: fontName.setStatus('mandatory')
```

Now this is a get on another column

```
pysnmp$ snmpget -v2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.4.1.1206.4.2.3.3.2.1.5.0 
iso.3.6.1.4.1.1206.4.2.3.3.2.1.5.0 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

defined like this

```
fontCharSpacing = MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 1206, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 5), Integer32().subtype(subtypeSpec=ValueRangeConstraint(0, 255))).setMaxAccess("readwrite")
if mibBuilder.loadTexts: fontCharSpacing.setStatus('mandatory')
```

This is the debugger feedback for a set on the same object to an i 4 which should be in range

```
ValueConstraintError: ConstraintsIntersection(ValueRangeConstraint(-2147483648, 2147483647), ValueRangeConstraint(1, 255)) failed at: ValueConstraintError('ValueRangeConstraint(1, 255) failed at: ValueConstraintError(0,)',) at Integer32
```

There are a couple more errors that I think are related, to me it all seems like the MIB.py file is not getting read correctly, probably because I am overriding some code when customizing the mib. With the next function

```
def createVariable(SuperClass, getValue, sValue, *args):
    """This is going to create a instance variable that we can export. 
    getValue is a function to call to retreive the value of the scalar
    """
    class Var(SuperClass):
        def readGet(self, name, *args):
            print " Getting var..."
            return name, self.syntax.clone(getValue())

        def writeTest(self, name, *args ):
            print " Testing var..."

        def writeCommit(self, name, val, *args ):
            print " Setting var..."
            sValue(val)

    return Var(*args)
```

I dont understand the structure of pysnmp so I cant traceback where things go wrong, so I can post the rest of the code if necessary, it is only a couple hundred lines long for this tests.

Thank you for any help provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement a dynamic SNMP table (where you can create/delete rows via SNMP SET) you should set up a hierarchy of `MibTable`, `MibTableRow` and `MibTableColumn` objects:

```
(MibTable,
 MibTableRow,
 MibTableColumn,
 MibScalarInstance) = mibBuilder.importSymbols(
    'SNMPv2-SMI',
    'MibTable',
    'MibTableRow',
    'MibTableColumn',
    'MibScalarInstance'
)
```

And register them with pysnmp under the OIDs that reflect objects hierarchy  e.g.:

```
RowStatus, = mibBuilder.importSymbols('SNMPv2-TC', 'RowStatus')

mibBuilder.exportSymbols(
    '__EXAMPLE-MIB',
    # table object
    exampleTable=MibTable((1, 3, 6, 6, 1)).setMaxAccess('readcreate'),
    # table row object, also carries references to table indices
    exampleTableEntry=MibTableRow((1, 3, 6, 6, 1, 5)).setMaxAccess('readcreate').setIndexNames((0, '__EXAMPLE-MIB', 'exampleTableColumn1')),
    # table column: string index
    exampleTableColumn1=MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 6, 1, 5, 1), v2c.OctetString()).setMaxAccess('readcreate'),
    # table column: string value
    exampleTableColumn2=MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 6, 1, 5, 2), v2c.OctetString()).setMaxAccess('readcreate'),
    # table column: integer value with default
    exampleTableColumn3=MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 6, 1, 5, 3), v2c.Integer32(123)).setMaxAccess('readcreate'),
    # table column: row status
    exampleTableStatus=MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 6, 1, 5, 4), RowStatus('notExists')).setMaxAccess('readcreate')
)
```

Make sure to state how table index should look like e.g. the trailing part of the OID that goes past `MibTableColumn` OID. You do that by configuring one or more columns to the `.setIndexNames()`.

If you want to be able to create/drop the whole row in one shot, you need to have a dedicated *status* column in your table with the value of type `RowStatus`. You can read the details on how `RowStatus` works in [RFC2579](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2579#section-2) (search for RowStatus).

By this point you should be able to create new rows:

```
$ snmpset -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.6.1.5.2.97.98.99 s “my value”
$ snmpset -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.6.1.5.4.97.98.99 i 4
```

(the `97.98.99` part of the OID corresponds to the `exampleTableColumn1` string value of `abc` which is an example index value).

As well as destroy the whole row:

```
$ snmpset -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 1.3.6.6.1.5.4.97.98.99 i 6
```

When you create/destroy columns this way, the `.createTest()`/`createCommit()` and `destroyTest()`/`destroyCommit()` methods get invoked on the `MibTableColumn` objects. The `writeTest()`/`writeCommit()` methods are invoked on value modification.
These are the methods you may want to override to control something outside pysnmp.

Complete example script can be [seen here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html#implementing-conceptual-table).

Note that we did not generate any code from ASN.1 MIB with `mibdump.py` so far.

If you need more hands-on help with the code, I'd advise moving to pysnmp [issues](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues) at GutHub.

### Theory shot

With SNMP, MIBs usage is two-fold. SNMP clients (e.g. managers) use MIBs as a "schema" to figure out the data they receive from the SNMP servers (e.g. agents). The latter actually implement concrete data structures based on the MIB schema (schema instance).

With pysnmp we use the same set of Python classes for both purposes.

- The  managers typically use just the schema objects (e.g. `MibTable`, `MibTableRow`, `MibTableColumn` and `MibScalar`)
- The agents put their data under control of the schema instance object (`MibScalarInstance`) possibly manipulated by the schema objects whenever you intend to manage the schema instance objects at run time.

This hopefully explains why pysnmp MIB management code looks similar for manager/agent implementations.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for answering so soon. I have seen the example, and will try to implement a solution using it. The code where you register the OID hierarchy is very similar to the code generated by mibdump.py, does it has the same purpose? and if it does do I change the generated code?

Comment: @DiegoVM commented on your question